# Opening a Access 2007 file

Tags: security, ms-access

I am trying to open an Access 2007 file that was secured from our client. When I double-click on it, it shows me the following error:

Error:
You do not have the necessary permissions to use the  object. Have your system administrator or the person who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you. (Error 3033)

On my search to this solution I understand that it is password protected by the Windows system, and not Access password. How would I solve this issue ?

Ref: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1663080.php

Comment: I'm quite puzzled as to why this is voted to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

No, error 3033 is coming from Access and thus the Access database file isn't secured by Windows but by Access.

What you need to do is to locate the MDW file that goes along with that database file and use it along with a client supplied Access userid and password to access the Access database file.  (incidentally that thread you reference has Joan Wild postings.  Anything she posts on the topic of security is well worth reading as she is one of the experts.  I am not.)

Now once you have the MDW file you will need to create a shortcut with the path and file name to your version of msaccess.exe, a space, then the path and file name of the Access database file, another space, /wrkgroup, a space and then the path and file name of the MDW file.   See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207 if any clarification required.   Note that if there are any spaces in the path and file names you will need to enclose that path and file name in double quotes.

The end result might be something like 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 2003\OFFICE11\MSACCESS.EXE" "Q:\1 access\database file.mdb" /wrkgrp "Q:\1 access\database file security.mdw"