# How to read an old Jet 3.5 database?

Tags: database, ms-access, dao, jet

I am trying to investigate an old DB file that used to have a custom front-end that dose not work anymore because of corrupted files.

The only clue I got is that it uses an old driver, a DAO Jet 3.5 (I have the driver installation file), and it used to run under windows XP.

The DB file itself doesn't have a known file extension.

What are my options for manually exploring the database?

Comment: which ISAM is it? if it is a microsoft access 97 database (mdb file), odds are good that you could still open and repair it in ms access 2000. then convert it to a newer format and access with oledb.

Comment: I don't know the file format..(the file itself doesn't contain any file extention). I tried to open it using access 2007 under a virtual xp environment but it dosen't work (something about mdw). should I try using  access 2000??

Comment: it has been a long time, but I remember when it asks about mdw, this means the file itself is an mdb (extension there or not...), and it needs the mdw (workgroup information file) because there the permissions are stored. that file should be part of the application's installation [see also here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/30540-open-access-database-with-missing-mdw-files)

Comment: if you want to be sure that it actually is a Microsoft Access database file, open it with a binary editor and look for the string "Standard Jet DB" at the beginning after the first few bytes.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think the back end is actually an MS Access file? The lack of a file extension may indicate a proprietary database/file format.

Comment: Ok, so I opend the file with a binary editor and I did see the Standard Jet DB. Now what I don't get is how the custom GUI is able to open the file? there isn't any mdw around, but still the GUI program is able to connect to the database somehow. I know this because before it crashes I can see in the logs that it successfuly conected to the DB. Any suggestions?

Comment: you said, 5 comments up, "something about mdw". what exactly does Access say when you File>Open the extensionless database? When the application starts, a proof for a successful connection would be the presence of an .ldb file in the same directory as the database, while the app is connected. is that the case? Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737797/opening-a-access-2007-file, and from there https://support.microsoft.com/de-at/kb/209207

Comment: the error is "You do not have the necessary permissions to use the…" (linke the one in this link: http://chrisstark.co/2013/01/microsoft-access-error-you-do-not-have-the-necessary-permissions-to-use-the/). there isn't any ldb file in the same directory while the app is connected. BTW I think I remember that about ten years ago I wrote a plugin for the GUI and I was able to connect to the database using a small wrapper library for ODBC, written in cpp

Comment: Here is the library I used: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4812/easyodbc . I can't remember how i was able to connect the DB but I remember that I needed to configure the DB as a data source in the windows ODBC.

Comment: Go for that. but I'm afraid when you open up the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator in Windows, select "User DSN", "MS Access Database", "Configure", you will be able to select, repair, and compact the file, but it would still ask for the MDW in the "System Database" section if one is associated with the db. You might also try to add the ".mdb" extension to a copy of your file, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @dlatikay , I just found out that you were right about the presence of an Idb file while the GUI makes the connection. Could it help me with something?? about your last comment, you were also right. it still ask me the mdw thing. How the hell does the custom GUI is able to connect without the mdw??

Comment: it just confirms that the GUI app really succeeds to connect, which means that the db is not beyond repair. if you find a system.mdw on the machine with the GUI, [try this](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2012/05/10/The-obscure-way-to-open-an-Access-97-database-with-MDW-Security-in-Access2010.aspx)
otherwise, [try this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?774227-RESOLVED-open-access-file-that-is-missing-it-s-mdw-in-office-2013)

Answer (score 1):

If the file has no extension, it might not be a Jet database. But assuming it is...

---

MS Access would be the most obvious thing to try, but it can fail on old enough database files.

An alternative is **MDB Viewer Plus** which can open and read very old MDB files, with a nice GUI. It is perfect for "manual exploration" of an MDB file.

http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm

> MDB Viewer Plus is a freeware viewer plus editor for opening Microsoft
> Access MDB and ACCDB database files. It does not need to be installed
> to run. It uses Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) which is
> installed as part of Windows.
>
> MDB Viewer Plus has been written to provide a free, quick and easy way
> to open, view, edit, filter, sort, import to, export from, modify and
> search MDB and ACCDB files. This is useful for software developers
> like myself who use Access databases as a backend database for their
> bespoke software. MDB Viewer Plus provides a convenient way to view
> and edit these databases.